# R - Creating Probability of Occurrence in data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, random, dataframe, probability

If I have to create a table containing 19 students, each student has 10 data of whether they go to class on time. I would like to randomize 100% on time rate, 90% on time rate and 80% on time rate to each of the student. I cannot think of a way to randomize the on time percentage to each individual.(For example, student #1 has on time rate of 90%, while student #2 has on time rate of 70%, etc.) It is what I come up with if all the students has on time rate of 90%.

```
ID<-data.frame(rep(1:19,each=10))
ID$DOSE<- c(replicate(19,
c(sample(rep(c("on time","late")),size=10,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.90,0.10)))))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems that the problem in your code is that you mistyped `TRUE` on `replace=TRUE`. What problems are you facing with your code?

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistabke.I would like to ask if I want to randomize the on time percentage for different students. For example, student #1 has on time rate of 90%, while student #2 has on time rate of 70%, etc.

Comment: Does each student have an independent probability of being late, which is known a priori?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the 19 students, just draw a random on-time rate

```
probs<-c(.9,.8,.7)
onTimeRates<-sample(probs,19,replace=TRUE)
[1] 0.8 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.7 0.7
```

Then for each of these students, draw 10 data for "on time", with the corresponding probabilities

```
x<-sapply(onTimeRates,function(x) sample(c('punctual','late'),10,replace=TRUE,prob=c(x,1-x) ))
```

Then collapse this variable `x` into your desired column.

```
ID$DOSE<-matrix(x,ncol=1)
```

Comment: Anyway to revert the downvote? It was completely accidental. When I try to undo the downvote, it shows the message "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.". Really sorry!

Comment: Maybe if you make a minor edit, I can change it back =]

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning a student a different probability and then use to random its behaviour to 
`on time`or `late`

1 Creating the `data.frame`

```
DF = data.frame(ID = rep(1:19,each=10))
```

2 Assigning a probability to each student:

```
DF$prob = rep(sample((70:100)/100,19,replace=TRUE),each=10)
```

3 Using the probability to sample `on time` or `late`:

```
DF$attend = sapply(DF$prob,function(x) {sample(c("on time","late"),prob = c(x,1-x),1)})
```